# Compute the complex number

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\left(\frac{\sqrt 5 - 1}4 + \frac{\sqrt{2\sqrt5 + 10}}4i\right)^5$$
Well guys I need to find the complex number in the structure $a+bi$. I found out it has to be the same as $(\cos(72)+\sin(72)*i)^5$ but I really don't know if this is the way?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that multiplying complex numbers is the same as adding their angles and multiplying their radii. So since you know this number is equivalent to $(\cos(72)+i\sin(72))^5$, which I'm trusting you on, you must have $$(\cos(72)+i\sin(72))^5 = (\cos(5\times72)+i\sin(5\times72)) = (\cos(360)+i\sin(360)) = 1$$